# Show that $(G,*)$ is a group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Suppose $G$ is the set of functions of the form $f(x) = ax+b$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers
and $a \ne 0$. Let $*$ denote the operation of composition of functions, $(f * g)(x) = f(g(x))$.

For this question I know have to prove associativity, closure and whatnot. However what I am confused about is what is $g(x)$ in this case. I havent had to prove composition of functions before.

Comment: Simply, $f(x) = a x + b$ and $g(x) = c x + d$, with $a, c \ne 0$.

Comment: Please note, for future reference, the $\LaTeX$ editing I did to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since you said you know that you "have to prove associativity, closure, and whatnot", you know what that means, i.e that the function '$*$' in this case, which is the operation invoked on the set $G$, has to obey all the things that you mentioned. The function '$*$' is an operation, i.e a function of two variables from the set $G$ to itself.

Since you also know that the set $G$ is a set of functions of the form $f(x)=ax+b$, the operation thus takes two such functions. It then makes sense to call one of them $f$ and the other $g$. So to answer your question, $g(x)$ is just one of the elements in $G$, just as with $f(x)$. You would preferably then write $g(x)=cx+d$, to distinguish it from $f(x)$ in this case, since the constants may be different.

For example, to prove closure you would have to prove that $f(x)*g(x)=(f*g)(x)=a(cx+d)+b\in G$, i.e that the result is a function of the form $h(x)=C_1x+C_2$, for some constants $C_1,C_2$.

I'll let you figure out the rest but get back if you need more help.

Comment: Thanks thats all I needed.